# Dynamically attach properties to an instance of ndb.Model and have them in the to_dict() representation

Tags: python, architecture, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, restful-architecture

I'm writing a REST api over Google App Engine NDB

I excluded existing libraries because I need control over transactions and caching.
I excluded Google Endpoints for a similar reason and also because I don't want to use the javascript client they provide.

When evaluating architectural decisions I encountered some problems and weird situations, this is because my experience with python and pythonic style is probably not big enough.

In this moment **I tried to come up with some guidelines that should shape my codebase:**

- in Handlers -> create the dictionary representation of the objects
  and return them as json; perform authentication and authorization
  checks
- encapsulate ndb interaction in Services
- Model classes always receive Model objects or keys as parameters and return Model objects or Model lists
- Model classes are imported and used in services

One particular thing I encountered is this
I have a **many to many relationship** that I implemented with a mapping Model, something like 
**UserOrganizationMembership**, that has the keys of the User and the Organization

now, in my Service, at some point I want to return an object that has the list of the organizations the current user is member of and recursively fetch the companies that are in each organization:

```
'organizations': [
  {
    'name': 'TEST'
    'companies': [ {company1}, {company2}]
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

I do this

```
  def user_organizatios_with_companies(user):
    def fetch_companies(x):
      x.companies = Company.by_organization(x) #NOTICE THIS
      return x

    user_organizations = [ membership.organization.get() for membership in UserOrganizationMembership.by_user(user)]
    return [fetch_companies(x) for x in user_organizations]
```

in the highlighted line **I attach the dynamic property 'companies' to the Organization Model**

now if I call this method in my Handler, when I create the dictionary representation to output json, **ndb.Model.to_dict() implementation ignores dynamically attached properties.**

**One solution I tried is this (in my Handler)**

```
xs = Service.user_organizatios_with_companies(u)
organizations = [x.to_dict() for x in xs]
for x in xrange(0,len(xs)):
  organizations[x]['companies'] = xs[x].to_dict()
```

**but I don't like it** because I need to know that each organization has a 'companies' property and the code seems a bit complicated and not obvious

**another approach is to override ndb.Model.to_dict()**
isolating dynamically attached properties and providing a dictionary representation, **this simplifies my code in the Handler letting me to only call to_dict()** on the stuff returned by the Service.

from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import util

```
class BaseModel(ndb.Model):
  created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
  updated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now = True)
  # App Engine clock times are always 
  # expressed in coordinated universal time (UTC).s

  def to_dict(self, include=None, exclude=None):
    result = super(BaseModel,self).to_dict(include=include, exclude=exclude)
    result['key'] = self.key.id() #get the key as a string
    # add properties dynamically added to the class
    dynamic_vars = {k:v for (k,v) in vars(self).iteritems() if not k.startswith('_')}
    for prop, val in dynamic_vars.iteritems():
      result[prop] = val.to_dict() if not isinstance(val, list) else [x.to_dict() for x in val]
    return util.model_db_to_object(result)
```

**do you have any recommendation against this approach? any thought will be appreciated!**

Answer (score 1):

ndb supports dynamic properties through the [Expando type](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#expando).

Instead of defining your models as:

```
class BaseModel(ndb.Model):
```

Define it using `Expando`:

```
class BaseModel(ndb.Expando):
```

Now, if you write `x.companies = [...]`, calling _to_dict() will output those companies. Just be careful about when you `put()` these entities, as any dynamically added properties will also be put into the Datastore.